# Как сделать возврат пустого объекта при вызове с аргументом null?

Tags: javascript

Всем здравствуйте, надо было создать аналог функции Object.create.

Написал, на что мозгов хватило, сейчас никак не могу додуматься, как исправить единственную ошибку в тесте: "должен возвращать пустой объект при вызове с аргументом null".

```js
Object.create = function(proto, propertiesObject) {
        let result = {};
        if (proto !== Object(proto) && proto !== null) {
            throw new TypeError('');
        }
        if (proto === null) {
            return result;
        }
         result = Object.setPrototypeOf({}, proto);
        if (propertiesObject !== undefined) {
            Object.defineProperties(result, propertiesObject);
        }
        return result;
};
```

Пример:

```js
const A = {
  objectName: 'Object A',
  getObjectName: function() {
    return `This is ${this.objectName}!`;
  },
};

const B = Object.create(A, {
  objectName: {
    value: 'Object B',
  },
});

A.getObjectName(); // This is Object A!
B.getObjectName(); // This is Object B!

A.hasOwnProperty('getObjectName'); // true
A.hasOwnProperty('objectName'); // true

B.hasOwnProperty('getObjectName'); // false
B.hasOwnProperty('objectName'); // true
```

Сейчас тест дает:

```js
  ● object-create › должен возвращать пустой объект при вызове с аргументом null

    expect(received).toBeNull()

    Received: {}

      25 |     const obj = Object.create(null);
      26 |     expect(obj).toEqual({});
    > 27 |     expect(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)).toBeNull();
         |                                        ^
      28 |   });
      29 | 
      30 |   it('аргумент `prototype` отрабатывает должным образом', () => {

      at Object.toBeNull test.js:27:40)
```

Comment: Приведите пример(добавьте console.log()  ) как работает сейчас и какого результата вы хотите достичь?(желаемый результат)

Comment: @SwaD, отредактировал

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```js
Object.create = function(proto, propertiesObject) {
    let result = {};
    let empty = {};
    empty.__proto__ = null;
    if (proto !== Object(proto) && proto !== null) {
         throw new TypeError('');
    }
    if (proto == null) {
        return empty;
    }
        result = Object.setPrototypeOf({}, proto);
    if (propertiesObject !== undefined) {
        Object.defineProperties(result, propertiesObject);
    }
    return result;
};
```